# Can TuxPaint be made full screen in Windows without changing the CLI arguments?

Tags: windows, fullscreen

In my school we have TuxPaint on our Windows computers. It opens in a very small window (compared to the size of the monitors).

I've read that you can make TuxPaint full screen by opening it with the `--fullscreen` option, but I can't change the desktop shortcut to add that option as I don't have admin access.

Is there a way to make TuxPaint change to full screen once it's been opened, perhaps through a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: Have you tried the default Windows key command for full screen: F11?

Comment: maybe `alt enter`

Comment: Unfortunately neither of those do anything.